# Find the total exposure of a tweet

Tags: twitter

Let's say I (100 followers) tweet X. Users A (500 followers), B (300 followers, including 100 that overlap with A) and C (1000 followers, of which 800 are unique) retweet it.

Is there a way to get a report of the total "exposure" of the tweet - all the people who have seen it? In this case, 100 + 500 + 200 + 800 = 1600.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [TweetReach](http://tweetreach.com/) which looks like it provides the analytics you are after.